# Чукотка обрезается на карте России из geojson, как исправить?

Tags: python, карты, geojson

[По ссылке](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/codeforamerica/click_that_hood/master/public/data/russia.geojson) скачал geojson файл с геометрией регионов россии

попробывал их визуализировать с помощью библиотеки geopandas:

```
df = gpd.read_file(r'russia.geojson')
df['VARIABLES'] = [85-i for i in range(df.shape[0])]
df.plot(figsize=(10, 6), column='VARIABLES', cmap='Blues')
```

В итоге Чукотку обрезало, как решить эту проблему?
[image: Вывод программы]

Comment: это стандартное разбиение карты по 180 меридиану. ищите другой json

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66833670/geopandas-map-centering-with-countries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш geojson устарел - ка карте отсутствуют новые регионы, но ради академического интереса:

В соответсcвии с RFC, данный json отображается в проекции `EPSG:4326`, то есть, с разделением карты по антимеридиану (180-й долготе). Можно сделать преобразование проекции в нестандартную `Asia lambert conformal conic` (она поддерживается не всем официальными сервисами) и получить то, что вам нужно:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

df = gpd.read_file(r'russia.geojson.txt')
df['VARIABLES'] = [85-i for i in range(df.shape[0])]
#задаем параметры новой проекции:
dict = {'proj': 'lcc', 'lat_1': 5, 'lat_2': 20, 'lat_0': 14.60004, 'lon_0': 120.98, 'x_0': 0, 'y_0': 0, 'datum': 'WGS84', 'units': 'm', 'no_defs': True}
#применяем проекцию
df = df.to_crs(dict)
df.plot(figsize=(10, 6), column='VARIABLES', cmap='Blues')
```

получаем:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу отметить, что линия разделения по антимеридиану все равно видно на карте. Если вам не хочется возиться с вычислением и объединением полигонов, и эта линия вам не сильно мешает, то оставьте ее так, как есть.